# How to speed up search in a huge dictionary

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, search, dictionary

I have a very huge dictionary and the content inside it looks like:
(headers not included in the dictionary)

```
(code)        (names)
------------------------------
910235487     Diabetes, tumors, sugar sick, .....
```

I have more than 150K lines of this kind of pairs in the dictionary.

**The user input is key words (diagnosis names), I cannot search the dictionary by keys.**

**Here is the code:**

```
var relevantIDs = this.dic.Where(ele => ele.Value.Contains(keyword)).Select(n => Convert.ToUInt64(n.Key));
```

The dictionary is `Dictionary<string, string>` and I have to use string as the data type of key, because the codes can sometimes contain characters. The names column contains a list of relevant diagnosis names. So I cannot change this data type either.

I think the problem is for each value of a pair, I did the `Contains` operation which slows down the who process, but I cannot find an alternative way to do so...

This is what I did in order to find the matched codes.
But the performance of this code is terrible (it takes around 5 mins to finish this single line of code).

Can someone help?

---

**Update and simplest solution:**

I finally found the season why the search is so slow, and solved it by doing so:

```
var relevantStringIDs = this.dic.Where(ele => ele.Value.Contains(keyword)).Tolist();
var relevantUlongIDs = relevantStringIDs.Select(n => Convert.ToUInt64(n.Key)).Tolist();
```

The reason why it was that slow is `this.dic.Where(ele => ele.Value.Contains(keyword))`, it will be executed every time whenever the second part of the query is executed (this is the feature of `IEnumberable<T>`, I forget the term for it (maybe delayed execution)). So I use `ToList()` to convert the delayed query to a concrete list in the memory so that the result can be reused when converting strings to `ulongs`, rather than execute the query again for each conversion.
Please correct me if you found something wrong in this explanation.

By the way, although this may not be the best solution but the performance of the changed code is quiet satisfactory. The first statement of the code only costs 169 ms which is quick enough for me.

Comment: hi guys, please don't downvote my question without telling me the reason. I have checked other similar questions but none of them really solved my problem.

Comment: If your codes can contain characters, you're going to gave a hard time converting them all to Int64...

Comment: The term is "[deferred execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx)". However, issuing an extra `ToList` between the `Where` and the `Select` is unlikely to help performance in this case. If you're iterating over the final result multiple times (which I assume you are), then you're benefiting mainly from the *final* `ToList`. Try changing your code from `dic.Where(...).ToList().Select(...).ToList()` to `dic.Where(...).Select(...).ToList()` – you will observe virtually no change in performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it the wrong way round. Dictionaries permit efficient lookups when you know the *key*, not the value.

A simple way of fixing performance would be to construct a reverse dictionary mimicking a full-text index over your content:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic.Add("910235487", "Diabetes, tumors, sugar sick");
dic.Add("120391052", "Fever, diabetes");

char[] delimiters = new char[] { ' ', ',' };

var wordCodes =
    from kvp in dic
    from word in kvp.Value.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    let code = long.Parse(kvp.Key)
    select new { Word = word, Code = code };

var fullTextIndex =
    wordCodes.ToLookup(wc => wc.Word, wc => wc.Code, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

long[] test1 = fullTextIndex["sugar"].ToArray();       // Gives 910235487
long[] test2 = fullTextIndex["diabetes"].ToArray();    // Gives 910235487, 120391052
```

The construction of the full-text index will take a long time; however, this is a one-off cost, and will be amortized through the time savings of subsequent lookups.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying :)

Comment: Hi Douglas, I found the problem hided in my code. But I like your way anyway, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you lose all of the speed benefits of the dictionary by iterating over it's values.  Dictionaries are optimized for key lookups.

I would approach this with a different datatype and optimize it for your keyword lookups.

Here's an example using LINQ to create a [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) from data similar to yours.  In this case, I'm building it directly from string data which avoids the dictionary entirely.

This type of lookup should perform much better.

```
string [] lines = {
"123 A, B, C, D",
"456 E, F, G",
"321 A, E, H, I",
"654 B, G",
"789 A, J, K, L",
"987 A, M, L, E"
};

var lookup = lines.SelectMany (
    l => (l.Split(new char[]{' '},2)[1]).Split(',').Select (v => v.Trim().ToLower()).ToArray(),
    (l,o) => new{
    keyword = o,
    code = Convert.ToInt64(l.Split(' ')[0])
}).ToLookup(k => k.keyword, v => v.code).Dump();

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",lookup["a"]));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",lookup["l"]));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",lookup["b"]));
```

Note that this assumes you are looking up whole keywords (your initial example could lookup partial keywords)